# Mi scrollView me superpone las etiquetas

Tags: swift, swift3

Estoy intentando hacer un *scroll view* que muestre en un *label* varios valores. Un valor por cada página. El *scroll view* me sale bien, pero el problema es que en lugar de mostrarme cada valor en una página diferente, me los acumula todos en la primera página, unos sobre otros.

Este es mi código:

```
class ConsejosController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var asunto = ["value1", "value2"]

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self

        for etiqueta in 0...1 {
            contentWidth += view.frame.width

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
            label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.text = asunto[etiqueta]
            self.scrollView.addSubview(label)
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.height)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / CGFloat(375) )
    }
}
```

Pero el problema es que en el *label* de la primera página me muestra los valores 'value1' y 'value2' uno encima del otro. Y en la segunda página, no me muestra nada. Yo lo que quiero es que en el *label* de la primera página muestra "value1" y en el *label* de la segunda página "value2". Pero no lo consigo hacer bien.

¿Alguna orientación?
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás poniendo los dos *labels* en la misma posición:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
```

Ya que estamos... ¿por qué le pones un *frame* que no es el que quieres y después le cambias el centro?

Lo que deberías hacer es sumarle un *offset* a la `x` para que el segundo *label* quede en la segunda página.

```
    var offset = 0
    for etiqueta in 0...1 {
        contentWidth += view.frame.width

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160 + offset, y: 285)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = asunto[etiqueta]
        self.scrollView.addSubview(label)
        offset += scrollView.size.width
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo Marcos. Efectivamente era eso lo que me faltaba. Mil gracias por tu ayuda!